# Update the data in directive when use ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have a stopwatch for every candidate.
The candidate info is in `ng-repeat` where I pass the doi (date of interview) value in `stop-watch` directive controller as below

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.directive('stopWatch', function() {
    debugger;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            name: "=",
            time: "=",
            timeOfInterview: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            debugger;
            $scope.getTimeRemaining = function(endtime) {
                debugger;
                $scope.t[$scope.name].total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
                $scope.t[$scope.name].seconds = Math.floor(($scope.t[$scope.name].total / 1000) % 60);
                $scope.t[$scope.name].minutes = Math.floor(($scope.t[$scope.name].total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
                $scope.t[$scope.name].hours = Math.floor(($scope.t[$scope.name].total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                $scope.t[$scope.name].days = Math.floor($scope.t[$scope.name].total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            }

            $scope.initializeClock = function(endtime) {
                debugger;
                $scope.t = {};
                $scope.t[$scope.name] = {};
                $scope.updateClock = function() {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.getTimeRemaining(endtime);
                    $scope.t[$scope.name].hours = ('0' + $scope.t[$scope.name].hours).slice(-2);
                    $scope.t[$scope.name].minutes = ('0' + $scope.t[$scope.name].minutes).slice(-2);
                    $scope.t[$scope.name].seconds = ('0' + $scope.t[$scope.name].seconds).slice(-2);

                    if ($scope.t[$scope.name].total <= 0) {
                        clearInterval($scope.timeinterval);
                    }
                }

                $scope.updateClock();
                $scope.timeinterval = setInterval($scope.updateClock, 1000);
            }


            $scope.initializeClock($scope.timeOfInterview);
        },
        templateUrl: './views/stopWatchView.html'
    };

});
```

above `$scope.t[$scope.name]` is to differentiate candidate.

The template html is as below

```
<div id="clockdiv">
<div class="tiles">
    <span class="days" ng-bind="t[name].days"></span>
    <span class="hours" ng-bind="t[name].hours"></span>
    <span class="minutes" ng-bind="t[name].minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds" ng-bind="t[name].seconds"></span>
</div>
<div class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
</div>
```

I am facing problem of timer counter is not updated every time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is because you use `window.setInterval` instead of [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)
So the digest cycle does not run and therefore your changes aren't noticed.

Try rewriting the line

```
$scope.timeinterval = setInterval($scope.updateClock, 1000);
```

to use angular's $interval, i.e. something like this

```
$scope.timeinterval= $interval($scope.updateClock, 1000)
```

Comment: Did you inject it?

Comment: hey @DAXaholic seems to be working, i forgot to inject.Thanks